# Upload file in FormData with builtin NodeJS `fetch`

Tags: node.js, file-upload, fetch, form-data

How to upload file with FormData using Node.JS built-in [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch) (not `node_fetch`)?

Answer (score 10):

To upload file as [`FormData`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-formdata) using NodeJS builtin [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch).
We read the file as [`Blob`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-blob) then `set` or `append` to the `FormData` object.
And finally we send the `FormData` object as the body of the `fetch` request.

To read the file as `Blob`, we can use the [`fs.openAsBlob`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsopenasblobpath-options) (Node.JS ^19.8) or read file `fs.readFile` as `Buffer` and convert it to `Blob`.

```js
import { openAsBlob } from 'node:fs' // Node.JS ^19.8
import { readFile } from "node:fs/promises"
import { lookup } from "mime-types"

uploadFile("./path/to/file.ext").then(res => res.text()).then(console.info)

async function uploadFile(/** @type {string} */ filePath) {
  const file = await openAsBlob(filePath); // or
  const file = new Blob([await readFile(filePath)], { type: lookup(filePath) });
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.set("file", file, "file_name.ext");
  return fetch(`https://example.com/upload`, { method:"POST", body:formData, /* ... */ });
}
```